# Is it really required SampleCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs, just started few days back,

I got a code which uses $http , working fine.

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []); // Define new module for our application

      // Create new controller, that accepts two services $scope and $http
      function SampleCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.date = "sample date"; // Bind data to $scope

    // Define new function in scope
    $scope.fetch = function() {
      // Use $http service to fetch data from the PHP web service
      $http.get('api.php').success(function(data) {
        $scope.date = data.date; // Bind the data returned from web service to $scope
      });
    }

  };

  SampleCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http']; // Ask Angular.js to inject the requested services,      
  sampleApp.controller('SampleCtrl', SampleCtrl); // Initialize controller in pre-defined module
```

========================
 I tried two things

**1.** when i commented the line  *`SampleCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];`* from the above code, the code still works, I need to know, why we need this or when we need this.

**2.** separating the fetch function like

```
function fetchData() {
          // Use $http service to fetch data from the PHP web service
          $http.get('api.php').success(function(data) {

             $scope.date = data.date; // Bind the data returned from web service to $scope
          });
          return $scope;
        }
      // Create new controller, that accepts two services $scope and $http
      function SampleCtrl($scope, $http) {
        // Define new function in scope
        $scope.fetch = fetchData($scope, $http);

      };
```

Sorry could not make jsfiddle, But here is the code which i am tried from

https://www.openshift.com/blogs/how-to-use-angularjs-with-php-hosting-on-openshift

In "`etting Started with Angular.js` section.

Answer (score 1):

This is done because of code minification. When you run your code with minifier, it will alternate the parameter names in `SampleCtrl` to `function SampleCtrl(a,b)` and you need to avoid this because dependency injector doesn't know which services to inject.

One solution is to use `$inject` as you did. It will make sure DI will inject correct services.

Another solution is to write controller in this style

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    // logic
}]);
```

these two ways are interchangeable

Comment: +1 for the 3rd option... I find that one the clearest.

Comment: It mostly depends on your code writing style which one is the most appropriate to use. If you prefer to define function first and then assign it via angular.module()[component] it's cleaner to use $inject. But if you are defining function on the fly inside module[component] I prefer the brackets injection

Comment: @doodeec, hey thanks, looks like you are correct, Can you please clarify my second doubt (2. separating the fetch function like). Is there any thing wrong over there

Comment: @SAM I don't know if it is a mistake - fetchData don't use any params so passing $scope and $http doesn't make sense... But I think separation is not a good approach with controllers. When you want to do it this way, just define fetchData as a local function within SampleCtrl and then reference it to the scope. But don't separate it completely from SampleCtrl, as you end up with 2 different functions which are dependent on $scope and $http instead of just one